# Route 53 hosted zome record points to old load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

**Problem**: I would like to change route 53 A record to point to a different load-balancer

Details:
I have **hosted-zone-1** called "website.com" with "A" record that points to load-balancer-1 using an alias. I updated that record and changed to so it points to **load-balancer-2**. I waited an hour and tried to access the above website but I am still taken to the old lb1. I have done some research and found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130362/route-53-alias-record-not-working) on StackOverflow which suggested doing the following steps:

> The simplest way out of that, is this:
>
> Leaving the existing zone exactly as it is, create a new hosted zone with the same domain. (Yes, this works).
>
> Note the four name servers assigned for the new hosted zone.
>
> Go to the domain record (the registrar component of Route 53, not the hosted zone component) and change the 4 name servers to match those assigned to your new hosted zone.
>
> In the new hosted zone, create a new A record, hostname box empty, Alias = Yes, and select the ELB name.
>
> Once it's working, delete the old hosted zone.

However, after following the steps above, again, I waited an hour I am still being taken to the old lb1 when accessing website.com.

```
nslookup website.com
```

Shows the lb1 dns address

I believe that behaviour is caused by the cache of the name resolver servers but I am wondering if there something that I can do to fix my problem faster so I don't have to wait for the cache to expire (provided that is the cause of the behaviour I am experiencing).

**UPDATE**:

executing:

```
dig website.com +trace +nodnssec
```

[image]

Which revealed that the website.com is not managed by Route53 but `akam.net` (i.e. Akamai). Which means that I will have to login to the akam.net portal and delegate the nameservers to the Route53 hosted zone or change the CNAME to point to load-balancer-2

Comment: Seems next time, you should check first if that domain is hosted on Route53 first which takes 5 mins but can save you from 2 hours :) anw, glad you found out the solution :D

Comment: @Leondkr Yes :D I learned my lesson not to assume but check :P